# ASP.NET web service does not work in Safari

Tags: safari

I have a WebForms page (.aspx) that accepts parameters via get / post and returns XML. This works in all browsers except for Safari where I get this gem:

```
Safari can’t open the page [URL]. The error was: “unknown error” 
(CFURLErrorDomain:303) Please choose Report Bugs to Apple from the Help menu, 
note the error number, and describe what you did before you saw this message.
```

Anyone see this before or know what it means?

**UPDATE:**

The web service is working for the http:// protocol, but fails under https://

Comment: you might want to report the bug..seems native to it.

Comment: Does "returns XML" means Resonse.Write("<?xml...")? If so what Content-Type headers are you sending to the browser?

Comment: I am setting the content-type to "text/xml" and am using Response.Write() to write the XML, The XML is valid and is created with XmlDocument class.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Worked via HTTP, didn't via HTTPS. Adding the Content-Length header fixed it for me:

```
Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", result.Length)

Context.Response.Write(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, this did the trick for us.

```
context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", FilInfo.Length.ToString())
```

http://bit.ly/RTSnr4

Answer (score 0):

Is it really Safari or is it Webkit?  That is have you tried it with Chrome and/or Konquerer?  It's possible that may give you an additional clue.